# window.print is not working for a page that has been rendered by document.write

Tags: javascript, html, printing

**Scenario:** 
I'm creating a new window (new tab) and writing html markup to it via javascript.
1. new document.
2. write html markup to document's content.
3. show the new document.

**What I need to do:**
I basically need to print a simple HTML page (javascript print dialog) by clicking on a button, link, or onload.
The problem, is i cant get either way to work... with one exception.

(the one exception) Using the onload="window.print()" will only work if the new window appears and i click refresh (the print dialog wont display upon initial creation of the window).

The weird thing is, even if i invoke "window.print()" on event clicks (href, button...etc) nothing happens. But I know it's not the browser because samples/demos of this SIMPLE thing works just fine.

So it seems it's somehow related to my page being rendered the way it is (described in the "Scenario" section of this).

**CODE:**
When i click on a Print button, i call this (right now it is not important exactly who/what calls this. but just know that it is called):

```
function Print(htmlContent) {
  var printWindow = window.open();
  var printDoc = printWindow.document;
  printDoc.write(htmlContent);
```

And i forgot to mention this: The HTML (htmlContent) that is passed to the Print scrip function is indeed Html, but it has been transformed by an XSL. Here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            .noprint{
                    display:none;
                }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function startPrint(){
                window.print();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

      <body>        
        <div >
            <a id="printButton" href="startPrint();">Print this page</a>
        </div>
        Hello world.
</body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can confirm javascript works because if i replace the href="startPrint()" with href="alert('hi')", i do indeed get a popup with that alert.

Comment: Post your code.  I'd make a pretty simple case (create window, make a "<span>Hello</span>" and then emit a <script>window.print();</script> at the end to see if that gets it.)  You might need defer="defer" on the script tag too.

Comment: Show the code for that scenario and we'll try to spot anything that might cause such problem. :)

Comment: Since the refresh page approach works (in the case where im using the onload event), i could possibly make the Print button/link invoke a page refresh, thus mysteriously causing the script function to be called. It would be a hack, but at least it would work (in theory).

Comment: What browser(s) are you using to test this? I get this exact same behavior but only in IE 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not clear with what actually you need to do with this code. But, from that I could understand & as per the reference available [here](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_print.cfm), I have implemented [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/zshLJ/).

This is working fine as you have mentioned regarding javascript print dialog onClick of link. But, still I think this doesn't seem your solution. Please correct me with my error.

Thank You.

For reference : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)